# How can I get data of simple URL through Retrofit, which is in JSON but that JSON has only IDs and no tag name?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

The code for Retrofit I have written is below, kindly tell me what I am doing wrong.
Also can someone tell me why we should use RxJava in which scenario and how it's more helpful than Volley which is backed by Android?

In Activity

```
 mService.getAnswers().enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
               // mAdapter.updateAnswers(response.body().getItems());
                Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
            }else {
                int statusCode  = response.code();
                // handle request errors depending on status code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
           // showErrorMessage();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create post" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("RETROFIT",t.toString());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

        }
    });
```

interface

```
public interface SOService {
   @GET("/topstories.json")
   Call<JsonObject> getAnswers();
}
```

and the Util is

```
public class ApiUtils {

   public static final String BASE_URL = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/";

   public static SOService getSOService() {
       return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(SOService.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: you have a Json array as a response

Comment: yes  [
  16125077,
  16125320,
  16124297,
  16124235,
  16125060,
  16125452,
  16119782,
  16121118,
  16123827,
  16125080,
  16124769,
  16123788,
  16122776,
  16121306,
  16121630,
  16123915,
  16125139,
  16122115,
  16124950,
  16119604,
  16120103,
  16123124,
  16123377,
  16121065,
  16122158,
  16123822,
  16121196,
  16123433 .....]    almost 500 ids

Comment: i would suggest you go through some examples first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove `/` from SoService then change `JsonObject` to `JsonArray` in every where so after change code look like this

interface

```
public interface SOService {
    @GET("topstories.json")
    Call<JsonArray> getAnswers();
  }
```

Activity

```
mService.getAnswers().enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                // mAdapter.updateAnswers(response.body().getItems());
                Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
            }else {
                int statusCode  = response.code();
                // handle request errors depending on status code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {
            // showErrorMessage();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create post" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("RETROFIT",t.toString());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

        }
    });
```

Note: import `com.google.gson.JsonArray` not `org.json`

Comment: Thanks Munir, i got the response.   but my second question is still pending        why we should use Rxjava in which scenario and how its more helpful than Volley which is backed by Android.?

Comment: @vink happy to help you..don't forgot to accept answer by tick right sign..)

Comment: @vink ReactiveX is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences. it's a huge concept you may get more on google.

Comment: Reffer this lik http://reactivex.io/intro.html, http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/ lots of other things just google it

Comment: i suggest to use Retrofit. it has more advantage over Volley.

Comment: Thanks Munir!  i have also tried implementing Rxjava into this and my first request is coming perfectly fine, but my second request is not even going inside the observable method so i can catch it in      public void onError(Throwable e)  . could you help me out on this.

Comment: @vink i am also new to Rx java so it's better to post a new question with the problem you have a face. so someone others helped you.